# Python - Class list and dictionnary linked between instance

Tags: python, class

I got a strange behavior with python class, that doesn't seem normal to me, could you take time to help me on that ?

The code has been executed under python 3.9 and 3.6.

I got multiple instances from the same class:

```py
class Obj:
    txt_list = []
    txt_dictionnary = {}
    txt_var = ""

    def __init__(self, txt):
        self.txt_list.append(txt)
        self.txt_dictionnary["hello"] = txt
        self.txt_var = txt
```

Main code :

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Obj1 = Obj("1")
    print(f"txt_list1 = {Obj1.txt_list} - txt_dictionnary1 = {Obj1.txt_dictionnary} - txt_var1 = {Obj1.txt_var}")
    Obj2 = Obj("2")
    print(f"txt_list1 = {Obj1.txt_list} - txt_dictionnary1 = {Obj1.txt_dictionnary} - txt_var1 = {Obj1.txt_var}")
    Obj2.txt_list.append("3")
    print(f"txt_list1 = {Obj1.txt_list} - txt_dictionnary1 = {Obj1.txt_dictionnary} - txt_var1 = {Obj1.txt_var}")
```

Output :

```
txt_list1 = ['1'] - txt_dictionnary1 = {'hello': '1'} - txt_var1 = 1
txt_list1 = ['1', '2'] - txt_dictionnary1 = {'hello': '2'} - txt_var1 = 1
txt_list1 = ['1', '2', '3'] - txt_dictionnary1 = {'hello': '2'} - txt_var1 = 1
```

For me `Obj1` shouldn't be changed when I instantiate and modify the `Obj2` since `Obj1` and `Obj2`.
We also see, only the simple variable don't change on modification/instantiation.
Did I forget something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`txt_list` here is a **class variable**, which means it is shared between all instances of the class. If you *mutate* it(like with `append` method), all the instances of the class will see the change.

In order to create a variable for *each* instance, you need to define an **instance variable**:

```py
class Obj:
    
    def __init__(self, txt):
        self.txt_list = [txt]
        self.txt_dictionnary = {'hello': txt}
        self.txt_var = txt
```

now `txt_list` is for individual instances, if you mutate it, no other instances will see the change.

I removed those lines from the class body, but I should mention that as long as you have those *instance variables*, you get the instance variables first. Even if they are defined as class variables as well.

```py
class Obj:
    txt_list = []
    txt_dictionnary = {}
    txt_var = ""
    
    def __init__(self, txt):
        self.txt_list = [txt]
        self.txt_dictionnary = {'hello': txt}
        self.txt_var = txt
```

This is how attribute lookup works in Python.(There are other cases where [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) come into play but that's not our concern at the moment. Just be aware that them)

You mention that:

> only the simple variable don't change on modification/instantiation.

That is because strings are immutable. You can't *mutate* it. When you do assignment, it doesn't *mutate* the object. So basically you create `txt_var` as instance  variable.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring `txt_list`, `txt_dictionnary`, and `txt_var` as class attributes.

As a result, all instances of your class share the same list and dictionary object, rather than have their own unique object.

Declare your attributes inside `__init__()` instead:

```
def __init__(self, txt):
    self.txt_list = [txt]
    self.txt_dictionnary = { "hello": txt }
    self.txt_var = txt
```